# jQuery and asp.net wont cooperate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm just trying to get jQuery to work on my page, but it's not going so well.
I've tried a lot of different solutions I've found online, but so far the only one that has worked is in code-behind. And only with "alert" nothing else.

```
button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(\"hello\")");
```

in page head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#button1").click(function(event){
         alert("Hello world!");
      });
   });
</script>
```

in page body:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="button" />
```

I get the button, but not a damn thing happens when i click it.

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot for quick answer `"#<%=button1.ClientID %>"` solved my problem, but a new one has shown it self.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#<%=button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
      $("#<%=div1.ClientID %>").fadeOut();
   });
});
```

It says that "div1" does not exist (although it certainly does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need this

```
button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(\"hello\")");
```

please check the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

   //client id************
   $("#<%=button1.ClientID %>").click(function(event){
      alert("Hello world!");
   });
  });
</script>
```

it will work. if you check your html source in the browser, you will see that button1 gets changed. if you use clientid, you will solve your problem

Comment: Just to make an additional comment: OP may also use the ClientMode attribute in the Page directive at the top of the page. E.g.  ClientIDMode="Static".. Also, please don't forget to return false in the jQuery click event handler to prevent a postback to the server.

Comment: please check the edit I made to my question. I'd be really thankfull if you could help me with that too ;)